# Как сделать правильный запрос?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Делаю такой вот AJAX запрос при помощи jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://services.sferainfo.net/api_school/?geo_school',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data){
    console.log("ok");
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

Возникает такая вот ошибка

> map.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://newglk.dev:8088' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: В вашем случае - никак.  Для того, чтобы cross-site запрос работал, нужно изменить конфигурацию на сервере services.sferainfo.net - если у вас нет доступа к этому серверу, то почитайте о [JSONP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: JSONP тоже не вариант, если API целевого сервера не поддерживает этого метода.

Comment: Тут у вас проблема связанная с тем, что посылать запрос можно только к тому серверу от которого получен документ (страница с которой идет запрос), это называется политика общего происхождения. Обойти ее можно через JSONP - то есть грузить как бы скрипты, или сервер должен давать соответствующий заголовок.

Comment: php curl - решение вашей задачи.