# Нет разрешения доступа к данным по api JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с получением данных по api.
Делаю запрос (убрал все лишнее для удобства):

```
try {
    fetch(API_SERVER)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json()
            .then(products => {
              console.log(products)
            })
        } else {
          console.log(new Error(response.status));
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
```

И получаю ошибку:

> Failed to load https://apiName: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>   localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Если делаю `fetch(API_SERVER, {mode: 'no-cors'})`, то вообще не понимаю, что происходит.
`console.log(new Error(response.status));` в консоль выводит `Error: 0`

Сначала думал, что дело в localhost, но при загрузке на хостинг ошибка та же. Скачал расширение для Chrome `Allow-control-allow-origin *`, при включенном расширении при `mode: 'cors'` ошибки никакой нет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема может быть и как ее решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том что API которая Вам должна ответить, не добавляет в заголовок: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, следственно безопасность браузера не позволит Вам принять данный запрос.

API которая должна Вам ответить должна иметь настроенный CORS.

Comment: Хм.. А как эту проблему тогда решает расширение `Allow-control-allow-origin *` ?

Comment: Видимо отключает безопасность браузера. Попробуйте через POSTMAN, там тоже у Вас ошибки не будет т.к. там нет компонентов безопасности браузера. Что за API Вы используете ?

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю что за POSTMAN.   
API дали для тестового задания. Наверно попробую у них узнать как получить данные...

Comment: POSTMAN это просто программа для разработчиков API, позволяет дернуть URL и получить ответ, задать параметры запроса и т.д. Это проблема на стороне API. Вот возможно этот вопрос, прольёт немного света на Вашу проблему. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520923/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81?rq=1